# Printing an array of objects javascript

Tags: javascript, html, array-of-dict

I am new to Javascript and I was trying to display an array of objects. I could not really make it happen. Because the number of objects in the array is more than one and each object has 2 attributes. 
eg

```
var person = {
    firstName : "John",
    lastName  : "Doe",
    age       : 50,
    eyeColor  : "blue"
};

var person1 = {
    firstName : "Ben",
    lastName  : "",
    age       : 44,
    eyeColor  : "brown"
};
var people = [];

people.push(person);
people.push(person1);
```

Now, if i want to print the "firstname" then what should i do for the script and the body of the html file?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Try to use Google. It's a tool to find stuff around the Internet(Internet is a network of computers).

Answer (score 2):

You access the attributes of an object like `person.firstName` `person.lastName` and so on.

Now considering they're in an array, you need to first write a loop till the array's length (Number of persons)

```
for(var i=0; i< people.length; i++)
```

Inside this loop, you can access the persons and their properties like:

```
people[i].firstName
```

So your complete working code should be like:

```js
var person = { firstName : "John", lastName : "Doe", age : 50, eyeColor : "blue" };

var person1 = { firstName : "Ben", lastName : "", age : 44, eyeColor : "brown" }; 
var people = [];

people.push(person); people.push(person1);


for(var i=0; i<people.length; i++){
  document.write(people[i].firstName + "<br>");
  document.write(people[i].lastName + "<br>");
  document.write(people[i].age + "<br>");
  document.write(people[i].eyeColor + "<br>");
}
```

im using document.write to display the result and `<br>` is used for the newline.

Answer (score 0):

For inserting the values in a div you can use innerHTML like this http://jsfiddle.net/w5b5drnr/1/ And to make the javascript code work you should insert it at the bottom of the page after all the content is ready :)

```
var people = [];

var result = document.getElementById('result');
var person = { firstName : "John", lastName : "Doe", age : 50, eyeColor : "blue" };
var person1 = { firstName : "Ben", lastName : "", age : 44, eyeColor : "brown" }; 

people.push(person); 
people.push(person1);

for(var i =0; i< people.length; i++){
    result.innerHTML += people[i].firstName + '<br/>';
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Following code will print car 1

```
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var cars = ["Car1", "Car2", "Car3"];
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = cars[0];
</script>

</body>
</html>
```